# CSS beginner, help creating this layout?

Tags: html, css

In the image below, on the left is the output of my html/css, on the right is what I would like the layout to look like.

I'm pretty clueless as to:

- how to Center the header
- why the 'upper right' text and button are being forced to the next line by the header (as opposed to orienting in the upper right
- how to align the text area so that it is to the right of the image

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer_border">
            <div class="inner_border">
                <!--just use a div to represent the image -->
                <div class ="image">
                </div>
                <span class="upper_left_text">
                    upper left
                </span>
                <span class ="header">
                    <h2>
                        Header
                    </h2>
                </span>
                <span class="upper_right_text">
                    upper right
                </span>
                <button class="button1">Button</button>
                <textarea class="text_area">Text Area</textarea>
                <button class="button2">Button 2</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

.outer_border {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
}

.inner_border {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
}

.image {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}



.the_header {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.button1 {
    float: right;
}

.button2 {
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
}

.text_area {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px;
    /*I have no idea how to position this*/
}

.upper_left_text {
    float: left;
}

.upper_right_text {
    float: right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you include the html/css that you currently have?

Comment: i was having trouble getting it to format properly, I include it now

Comment: put a js fiddle is easier people help :)

Comment: One option for your header, if you want it to be centered within the inner_border div, you can add `position: relative` to `inner_border` and `position: absolute; left: 40%;` to your `header` div. Adjust the left percentage to keep it centered. I don't recommend it but it's an option. A simple and clean layout like Medda86 suggests is probably the best way to go, lots you can do to customize it all from his template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle, check this one, should get you started :)

https://jsfiddle.net/fazbyxyq/

html5

```
<div class="right">
    <div>upper left</div>
    <div>header</div>
    <div>upper right</div>
    <div><textarea>textarea</textarea></div>
    <div>button2</div>
</div>
```

css3

```
*{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.left{
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.right{
    float:left;
    width:89%;
    margin-left:1%;
}

.right div{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.right div:nth-child(2){
    text-align:center;
}

.right div:nth-child(3){
    text-align:right;
}

.right div:nth-child(4),.right div:nth-child(5){
    width:99%;
    border:0;
}

.right div:nth-child(4) textarea{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px 0;
}

.right div:nth-child(5){
    text-align:right;
}
```

Peace out!

Comment: thanks, all the responses were helpful and informative.

Answer (score 1):

well, Your code was wrong in many lvl's. I have fixed it to look like in your image... but it's just a fix. Maybe not what you are looking for.

As a resume: You want a container with an image looks like a column and the rest of the html stay as another column.

Then, as you did, the image container is floating left with a fixed width of 50px but we have to add 10px more as you have given the container 5px margin (5px right and left = 10px),

Then I just add a container which will take the rest of the html. THen it's easy to give the container a float left and as its width 340px so the total of your layout is, as you want, 400px.

I have added both `box-sizing: border-box;` to make the border be inside the containers and not messing with the fixed widths.

Then I just have added `.header {float:left;}` as basically ion your code you have a class named `the_header`which is not even used in the html. and then a bit of margin to the h2 to separete it from `upper left`

here you have the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/a3op6z79/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

The key lays in treating your layout as a layout with 2 columns. I believe the markup should look something like this:

```
<div id='demo'>
    <div class='col1'>
        <img src='http://www.placehold.it/50x100' />
    </div>
    <div class='col2'>
        <div class='header'>
            <span class='left'>left</span>
            <span class='right'>
                <button>button</button>
                right
            </span>
            <h2>center</h2>
        </div>
        <textarea>Lorem ipsum</textarea>
        <button>button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

to achieve the result in your image, you should add the following css:

```
#demo {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
#demo .col1, #demo .col2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#demo .col2 {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
#demo .left {
    float: left;
}
#demo .right {
    float: right;
}
#demo .header {
    text-align: center;
}
#demo textarea {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
#demo button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Note that I've used as little fixed dimesions as possible. Just cause it will make your layout adapt easier to different content and different screen sizes.

I've put your code next to my proposal in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0k9ur09/). I think the code should be fairly easy and self explanatory, but feel free to ask if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another fiddle that uses the "calc" operation to set the textarea the remaining width of the div.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/tyokk1qj/

I wrap this image in  and set the height to 100% and then modify the rest of the elements to the right use CSS

```
.outer_border {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 600px;
 height: 500px;
}

.inner_border {
 border: 3px solid black;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
}
#tall{
 height:100%;
 float:left;
}
.image {
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 5px;
 float: left;
}
.the_header {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}
h2 {
 display:inline;
}

.button1 {
 float: right;
}

.button2 {
 width: 80px;
 height: 60px;
 display: block;
 float:right;
}

.text_area {
  clear: both;
  display: inline;
  width:auto;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.upper_left_text {
 float: left;
}

.upper_right_text {
 float: right;
}

.text_area{
  width:calc(100% - 70px);
}
```